# How to use custom Service Providers in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a Laravel app that needs to communicate with a remote (in-house) service via API.

This API needs to be authenticated at least once per session, and after that other calls can work fine.

I think the best way is to use Laravel's service providers to do this, but I'm open to other solutions.

### What I would like:

What I would like is a way to have this Service available for use whenever. I don't want to have to put the service in the parameters of a controller's method if I can avoid it. Something like this:

```
use MyServiceProvider;

class SomeController extends Controller 
{
    public function someMethod ()
    {
        MyServiceProvider::method();
    }
}
```

I can post what I've started doing thus far, if needed - but I'd rather focus on *doing what I want* rather than *fixing what I did wrong*.

**inb4:** I did read the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is create a Facade.  Facades are very similar to using dependency injection, except that they can be used globally without specific injection.  Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades#creating-facades

In your service provider:

```
App::bind('foo', function()
{
    return new \MyServices\Foo; //returns a concrete class
});
```

Foo.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Foo extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'foo'; } //matches binding in SP

}
```

Now your service provider is available as `Foo` anywhere, even without explicitly injecting it:

```
use Foo;

class SomeController extends Controller 
{
    public function someMethod ()
    {
        Foo::method(); //creates a Foo object according to App::bind, then calls method();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks about right. Let me tinker and see if this works :)

Comment: I can't seem to get it working.. I've placed my service provider and my facade in the same folder, gave them slightly different namespaces (`\Whatever` for provider; `\Whatever\Facades` for the facade) and included them in `config/app.php` under both `providers` and `aliases`. When I try to use it in my controller, I get `Class 'Whatever\Facades\MyServiceProvider' not found`. Tried googling and many guides have not worked :(

Comment: @Martin You may need to add the Service Provider to the array in `config/app.php`, have you done that?

Comment: Yeah, I added it there (the facade under `aliases` and the provider under `providers`)

Comment: `composer dump-auto` works (and by works I mean it doesn't throw errors but it does not resolve my problem), but `php artisan cache:clear` gives me the same error: `Class SoAndSo not found`

Comment: Try removing the service providers from the arrays, then clearing the cache and running artisan cache:clear/optimize, then adding the service provider and facade back into `app.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104575/discussion-between-martin-and-jeff).